# Mathematical arithmetic rounding $1$

Tags: arithmetic

What is an example of $4$-digit arithmetic rounding:
$
\text{ }\\
\text{a)}\\
11.2468 =  11.25\\
\text{ }\\
\text{b)}\\
0.25632 = 0.256\\
\text{or}\\
0.25632=0.2563\\
$

Can you explain what is correct in example $\text{b)}$?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine multiplying everything by 10: 2.5632 rounds to 2.563. It's the same if we didn't multiply by 10: 0.25632 rounds to 0.2563. Similarly,0.025632 rounds to 0.02563. The rounding process is invariant under multiplying or dividing by powers of 10.